# Getting ERROR: permission denied for function list_postgres_log_files

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get csv_logs from Postgres database. admin user can see the csv log files but other user which I created is getting an error. These are my steps:

```
Login as admin user
Execute: SELECT * FROM my_extensions.list_postgres_log_files() ORDER BY 1; --- This works and I can see log files

1.CREATE ROLE foo; -- a non-superuser
2.GRANT pg_monitor TO foo; -- do this only when list_postgres_log_files() is used because the underlying function pg_ls_logdir() needs it
3.GRANT USAGE,CREATE ON SCHEMA my_extensions TO foo; -- to create foreign tables in schema 
4.GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER my_log_server TO foo; -- to use log_fdw foreign server
5.SET ROLE foo;
6.SELECT * FROM my_extensions.list_postgres_log_files() ORDER BY 1; Throws an error: ERROR:  permission denied for function list_postgres_log_files SQL state: 42501


mydb=> \df+ list_postgres_log_files
                                                                                                                     List of functions
     Schema     |          Name           | Result data type |              Argument data types               | Type | Volatility | Parallel |     O
wner     | Security |       Access privileges       | Language |       Source code       | Description
----------------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------+------+------------+----------+------
---------+----------+-------------------------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------
 my_extensions | list_postgres_log_files | SETOF record     | OUT file_name text, OUT file_size_bytes bigint | func | volatile   | unsafe   | rds_s
uperuser | invoker  | rds_superuser=X/rds_superuser | c        | list_postgres_log_files |
(1 row)
```

I followed steps on https://github.com/aws/postgresql-logfdw
But my I am not able to view log files

Comment: Looks like you did not follow all the steps, I don't see: `SELECT * FROM create_foreign_table_for_log_file('log_file_tbl', 'log_fdw_server', 'log_file.csv');`

Comment: But I need to get list of csv log files first using list_postgres_log_files() function before creating foreign table on csv file

Comment: To your question add the text output of, in `psql`, the command `\df+ list_postgres_log_files`.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with AWS RDS permissions, therefore I'm going out on a limb here. I would try(as superuser) `GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION list_postgres_log_files TO foo;`

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly grant permission on the function, which was not mentioned in the Github steps. I thought `pg_monitor grant` would do the trick.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION my_extensions.list_postgres_log_files() to foo;
```